# Figuring out types of function composition by hand or mentally

Tags: haskell, type-systems

My attempt is currently like this: if I had `(.) const const`. First

```
(.) const :: 
(b→c)→((a→b)→(a→c)) (a→(b→a)) = 
(b→c)→((a→b)→(a→c)) (b→(d→b)) = -- (1) See below question
(a→b)→(a→(d→b)) = -- substitute (b→c) by (b→(d→b))
```

Next

```
(.) const const :: 
(a→b)→(a→(d→b)) (a→(b→a)) =
(a→b)→(a→(d→b)) (a→(e→a)) = -- (1) See below question
a→(d→(e→a)) -- substitute (a→b) by (a→(e→a)
```

1. I knew some variables had to match, some were different but had same name as coincidence, and changed it. Is there a formal, correct way of doing it?
2. I want to do it mentally, are there good exercises? Where should I start?

Knowing the result of function composition seems like hugely productive skill if someone is programming in FP language.

Comment: This kind of code rarely comes up in practice (except for people who write point-free code at all costs), and is usually far less readable than the alternatives. I wouldn't worry about it too much.

Comment: Mentally I’d do this by first inlining the definition of `(.)` to get `\x -> const (const x)`—assume `x :: a`, then `const x :: b -> a`, so `const (const x) :: c -> b -> a`, and finally `(\x -> const (const x)) :: a -> c -> b -> a`. As for the formal process of renaming variables (in this case, type variables), that’s called *alpha conversion* (e.g. `a -> c -> b -> a` can be renamed to `x -> y -> z -> x` by `a`→`x`, `b`→`z`, `c`→`y`), which is *capture-avoiding* (e.g. `\x -> x + y` can be renamed to `\z -> z + y` but not `\y -> y + y` because the latter changes what the second `y` refers to).

Comment: @JonPurdy oh yes! Doing some lambda calculus seems like a good idea! `\x -> (\a b -> a) ((\a b -> a) x) = \x -> (\a c -> a) (\b -> x) = \x -> \c -> \b -> x`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how I do it mentally.

I have a function of type `x->y` and a function of type `z->t`. If I want to compose them, `y` and `z` must be the same type, and the result will be of type `x->t`.

For `const . const` both functions have type `a -> (b -> a)`, but I need to rename variables in order to avoid clashes. So I have `a->(b->a)` and `c->(d->c)`. Now `c` is the same as `b->a`. I substitute the latter in the second type, and the final result is `a->d->b->a`.

Comment: how about (.) . (.) ?

Comment: @DulguunOtgon What about it? It would be the same process.

Comment: The Owl operator!

Comment: @4castle I can do it by hand, but not mentally.

Comment: I guess a useful trick to do it mentally is to remember currying and uncurrying,  Unifying one argument gets you a partial function, and you can think of the final few arguments as a function taking all but the last.  So, when you see a result like `(b->c) -> (d->e->b) -> d -> e -> c`, that’s really the same as `(b->c) -> (d->e->b) -> (d->e->c)`.  Or, in plain English, if you have a function that takes two arguments and returns a `b`, and apply a functor that consumes that `b` and returns a `c`, you get a function of two arguments that returns a `c`.,

Comment: @DulguunOtgon no, I have derived this from scratch, reasoning exactly as written. I didn't look at your derivation and had no idea what result to expect.

Comment: @n.m. Oops, it was a reply to Davislor. Forgot to include the name tag, sorry.

Comment: @Davislor I think that's about understanding the result. But I'm more interested in how that result came to be, coming up with it inside my head or some intuition.

Answer (score 0):

Learning lambda calculus, simply typed lambda calculus seems like a good start for more vigorous approach.

```
(\f g x -> f (g x)) (\a b -> a) (\a b -> a) =
(\x -> (\a b -> a) ((\a b -> a) x)) =
(\x -> (\a b -> a) (\b -> x)) = 
(\x -> (\a b -> a) (\c -> x)) = 
(\x -> (\b -> (\c -> x)))
```